# Sharepoint List Data extraction issue with SSIS

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

I am facing an issue with Extracting sharepoint list data through SSIS.i have excel file uploaded into sharepoint and there are 3 levels where the excel file is located for example DTZ>2014>FEB>Excel file...Please let me know how to extract the data from sharepoint with

Comment: You would like to get data out of a SharePoint list. Could be better explain *how* you are attempting to do this and *what* it is not working with this approach? It will also be helpful to know which version of SSIS and SharePoint you are working with.

Comment: I am using SSIS 2012 with Share point 2010 in a clustered environment.I am trying to pull data from excel to my database but due to unwanted issue system is not able to find the file and gets failed.I have integrated sharepoint list adapters in order to pull from the library.As per the object model we have everything in sharepoint as list so i am trying to fetch from these library.Please let me know if there is some confusion.